# How to use find utility with logical operators and post processing

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, find

Is there way to find all directories that have executable file that matches a partial name of parent directory?

Situation

```
/distribution/software_a_v1.0.0/software_a 
/distribution/software_a_v1.0.1/software_a
/distribution/software_a_v1.0.2/config.cfg
```

I need result

```
/distribution/software_a_v1.0.0/software_a 
/distribution/software_a_v1.0.1/software_a
```

I've gotten only so far

```
find /distribution -maxdepth 1 -type d  #and at depth 2 -type f -perm /u=x and binary name matches directory name, minus version
```

Comment: `echo /distribution/*/software_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using awk:

```
find /path -type f -perm -u=x -print | awk -F/ '{ rec=$0; sub(/_v[0-9].*$/,"",$(NF-1)); if( $NF == $(NF-1) ) print rec }'
```

The awk part is based on your sample and stated condition `... name matches directory name, minus version`. Modify it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep:

```
find /distribution -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep "/distribution/software_\w_v\d*?\.\d*?\.\d*?/software_\w"
```

Comment: `find` has a `-regex` option.

Comment: Close. But I don't know software names prior the search. I need name match. `/production/{unknown_name}_v.0.0.0/{same_unknown_name}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most efficient, but here's one way you could do it, using just `bash`...

```
for f in /distribution/*/*
do
  if [[ -f "${f}" && -x "${f}" ]]                  # it's a file and executable
  then
    b="${f##*/}                                    # get just the filename
    [[ "${f}" =~ "/distribution/${b}*/${b}" ]] && echo "${f}"
  fi
done
```